# Assign ImageUrl value from Image control to image html control

Tags: jquery

I have next user control:

```
<div class="page" >
     <div class="box cf">
    <div class="left">
       <span class="demowrap">
                <asp:Image ID="imgIdCard" class="imgClass" runat ="server" />
            </span>            
            <input type="button" value="Resize"  onclick="Zoom()" />
    </div>
      </div>
    <div id="dialogImage">
        <img id="imageDialog"/>
    </div>          
</div>
```

When I click in button value="Resize" I want to pass the ImageUrl value from ID="imgIdCard" to the src value img id="imageDialog".

I made next below code, but it's not working:

```
function Zoom(){
    var img = $(this).parent().select(".imgClass");
    $("#imageDialog").attr('src', img.attr('src'));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the key word `this` is not available to `zoom` function. Pass the current object using this, also use find instead of select. You can use closest instead of parent to find the common ancestor of image object and the button being clicked with `class` left.

*Html*

```
<input type="button" value="Resize"  onclick="Zoom(this)" />
```

*Javascript*

```
function Zoom(imgObj){
    var img = $(imgObj).closest('.left').find(".imgClass");
    $("#imageDialog").attr('src', img.attr('src'));
}
```

You can assign some id to your image button and `bind` event using `jQuery` then this will be available in the handler.

*Html*

```
<input id="mybutton" type="button" value="Resize" />
```

*Javascript*

```
$('#mybutton').click(function (){
    var img = $(this).closest('.left').find(".imgClass");
    $("#imageDialog").attr('src', img.attr('src'));
});
```

Comment: Excellent! It's great... It's working well. Thank so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You were very close. Replace `select` with `find`

```
var img = elem.parent().find(".imgClass");
```

`$(this).parent()` will give you the span with class `demowrap` & `.find('class')` will give you the child with the specified class.

Oh yes, also pass the element to the function Zoom like this `onclick="Zoom(this)"`
and use function Zoom(elem) {}

```
function Zoom(elem){
    var img = elem.parent().find(".imgClass");
    $("#imageDialog").attr('src', img.attr('src'));
}
```